# How can I replace an exising file into the assets folder with a refresh stuff?

Tags: c++, c, qt, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm develepping a BB10 mobile application using the momentics IDE.

I'm trying to save somes images coming from server into the "assets/images" folder using the Qt QFile object (you can see the code below) :

```
    m_file = new QFile(argSavingFilePath);

    if (m_file->exists()) {
        m_file->remove();
    }

    m_file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    m_file->write(argDataLoaded);
    m_file->close();
    m_file->~QFile();
```

It seems that is working but even if I exit out of the screen in question with the back button and then return it still doesn't show the latest image. It only works when I exit the app completely and launch a new instance.

According to this forum  [[link]](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/QFile-remove-not-immediately-effective/td-p/2522337), they said :

***"What's happening is that when you first load the image it gets read from the file system and then cached in memory. The app never goes back to re-read the image from the file. You would have to initiate that yourself."***

How should I initiate the cashed memory myself ? is this the only solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Whether the data is cached in memory or not is immaterial. The asset directory, in fact everything below and including the app directory is protected and immutable.

If you want to store data from a server the place to put it would be in data if you want it to persist, or tmp if not. Data in the tmp director is subject to removal by the OS when storage is needed for other things.

See: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/file_system.html